# Google App Engine NDB creating __metadata__ properties

Tags: google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

I've been using Google App Engine to develop a prototype inventory application.  I've recently switched from using the old DB datastore library to using the new NDB library, and the features are cool, but in making a change to one of my entities, suddenly NDB is inserting a property called "**metadata**" in my entity.  Here's the entity description (the change I made was to add the "inv_posid" and "inv_lastchange" properties, nothing major):

```
class Inventory(ndb.Model):
    inv_product = ndb.KeyProperty(kind = Product)
    inv_prdcr_name = ndb.StringProperty(default="")
    inv_product_type = ndb.StringProperty(default="")
    inv_product_name = ndb.StringProperty(default="")
    inv_product_year = ndb.IntegerProperty(default=0)
    inv_count = ndb.IntegerProperty(default=0)
    inv_price = ndb.IntegerProperty(default=0)
    inv_glass_price = ndb.IntegerProperty(default=0)
    inv_bin = ndb.StringProperty(default="")
    inv_posid = ndb.StringProperty(default="")
    inv_lastchange = ndb.FloatProperty(default=0.0)
```

With adding the new properties, I intended to change my query to use the "inv_lastchange" as a filter, and since NDB never includes entities in results that don't have the appropriate property included, I wanted to run a quick sweep through my datastore, to add the properties to all the entities appropriately.  So, here's what I did:

```
...
@ndb.tasklet
def fixInventory(invitem):
    invitem.inv_posid = ""
    invitem.inv_lastchange = 0.0
    invkey = yield invitem.put_async()

inventory = Inventory.query()
output = inventory.map(fixInventory)
```

I thought it would be neat to play around with tasklets and see how the asynchronous calls worked.  However, after doing that, when I went to look in the datastore viewer (on my local datastore), I saw this new "**metadata**" property, which I just assumed was something NDB needed to have, so I didn't think anything of it.

Until, the next time I tried to update one of my inventory items, I got this error:

```
  File "/Programming/VirtualCellar/server/virtsom.py", line 2118, in get
    inventory.put()
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/ndb/model.py", line 3432, in _put
    return self._put_async(**ctx_options).get_result()
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/ndb/tasklets.py", line 326, in get_result
    self.check_success()
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/ndb/tasklets.py", line 369, in _help_tasklet_along
    value = gen.throw(exc.__class__, exc, tb)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/ndb/context.py", line 810, in put
    key = yield self._put_batcher.add(entity, options)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/ndb/tasklets.py", line 369, in _help_tasklet_along
    value = gen.throw(exc.__class__, exc, tb)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/ndb/context.py", line 343, in _put_tasklet
    keys = yield self._conn.async_put(options, datastore_entities)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/ndb/tasklets.py", line 455, in _on_rpc_completion
    result = rpc.get_result()
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/apiproxy_stub_map.py", line 613, in get_result
    return self.__get_result_hook(self)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/datastore/datastore_rpc.py", line 1882, in __put_hook
    self.check_rpc_success(rpc)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/datastore/datastore_rpc.py", line 1373, in check_rpc_success
    raise _ToDatastoreError(err)
BadRequestError: cannot store entity with reserved property name '__metadata__'
```

So what's happening?  Is there something that I'm forgetting to do here?  It feels like the "**metadata**" property is supposed to be hidden or protected in some way, but it has been added just like a regular property, which is now preventing any other saves to be made to the entity.  Anybody run across this before?

Comment: I never heard about `ndb` automatically creating a `metadata` property. Are you certain the property didn't exist before? How exactly did you change your entity when this property popped up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `__metadata__` property is added to entities when they are saved to the datastore and removed when they are read from the datastore.  This is done in the `_ToStorageEntity` and `_FromStorageEntity` functions in `google/appengine/datastore/datastore_stub_util.py`.

Presumably internal failure has corrupted your entities somehow.

You might be able to recover by removing the `__metadata__` property from your entity instances' `_properties` dict and saving.

For example:

```
for inv in Inventory.query():
    del inv._properties['__metadata__']
    inv.put()
```

(Maybe backup your local datastore file before trying this, as a precaution against accidents).

Comment: `ndb` doesn't allow properties that start with _ but `db` does.  You might try doing the fix with `db`.

Comment: @JeffO'Neill I have a faint memory of having hit this in the past, but having fixed it without having to drop down to `db`, though I could be mistaken.  Hopefully the OP will report back and let us know what happens.

Answer (score 2):

So, based on what *snakecharmerb* said above, I started looking at why my datastore viewer was also showing me the `__metadata__` property, and it turned out that I had previously downloaded an older version of the google app engine SDK, and for some reason, my environment variables were still pointing to that old version, even though I had installed the latest version of the SDK a couple of times.  I wiped all traces of the google app engine SDK off my machine, and re-installed the SDK from scratch, and *voila!*  The `__metadata__` properties went away, in both the datastore viewer, and my own code!  My current hypothesis is that the older version of the `google/appengine/datastore/datastore_stub_util.py` file wasn't handling the `__metadata__` property in the same way.

Thanks so much for the help!